# JLabel display too short in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have a problem here where my GridLayout fixed the size of every JLabel.

the display by JLabel is too small for it to show the Object(a text).

Here is part of my code
`

```
    sjpc.add(changing01);sjpc.add(changing13);sjpc.add(changing25);
    sjpc.add(changing02);sjpc.add(changing14);sjpc.add(changing26);
    sjpc.add(changing03);sjpc.add(changing15);sjpc.add(changing27);
    sjpc.add(changing04);sjpc.add(changing16);sjpc.add(changing28);
    sjpc.add(changing05);sjpc.add(changing17);sjpc.add(changing29);
    sjpc.add(changing06);sjpc.add(changing18);sjpc.add(changing30);
    sjpc.add(changing07);sjpc.add(changing19);sjpc.add(changing31);
    sjpc.add(changing08);sjpc.add(changing20);sjpc.add(changing32);
    sjpc.add(changing09);sjpc.add(changing21);sjpc.add(changing33);
    sjpc.add(changing10);sjpc.add(changing22);sjpc.add(changing34);
    sjpc.add(changing11);sjpc.add(changing23);sjpc.add(changing35);
    sjpc.add(changing12);sjpc.add(changing24);sjpc.add(changing36);

    changing01.setText(txtf1.getText());

    if(Searching.exists())
    {
        try
        {
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Searching));
        reader.readObject();
        for(int i = 0 ; i <13 ; i++)
        {
            if(i ==0) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing03.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==1) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing09.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==2) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing04.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==3) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing06.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==4) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing18.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==5) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing30.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==6) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing07.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==7) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing21.setText(bFile.toString());
            }
            if(i ==8) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing10.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==9) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing22.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==10) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing11.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==11) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing23.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }
            if(i ==12) 
            {   
            Object bFile = reader.readObject();
            changing35.setText(bFile.toString());   
            }

        }
        reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException r)
        {
        r.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException q)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Not Found","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

`
Everything inside the JFrame are just JLabel. 
How can I expend the JLabel so that the sentence can be fully display in the frame? Does it need to overlap the JLabel at the right hand side to show the full sentence? If so, how?

Comment: Perhaps you might light to enlighten us with what it is you are trying to achieve, that way we might be in a better position to offer advice...

Comment: It would also be nice to see what is `sjpc`, how it is built etc... It's obvious that this code could be a lot shorter and much simpler using a `List<JLabel>` and a for-loop. My guess is that you should rather use a `JTable` than a bunch of `JLabel`'s inside what I imagine is a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`

Comment: My problem here is actually , I load something from an IO file and then put it as a Label. The Label is inside a Panel where the Panel is set with GridLayout. But the Label is too short for me to display the object(a text). 

Sorry, Im a beginner in Java. About the for loop, i put it like because it is easy for me to replace it with the "if" statement down there.

Comment: @Szekuns Definitely looks like a job for `JTable` rather than a `JPanel` with many `JLabel`'s. If you want a good (straight to use) anwser, provide us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and notify us with an "@username" comment (see help on comments for details). I can guarantee you that you will get a very valuable answer after providing the SSCCE.